# Error in Heroku does not make sense, application runs fine locally. RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, conditional-statements, helper, production

My application seems to be running fine locally. All of my code seems correct. My error is telling me that it could not find a record.

I have a model called cart which is related to users through session variables, I use the current_cart helper method to relate users to their carts. My error and code is below:

### error

```
2013-07-14T23:53:08.615652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-14T23:53:09.480513+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.2.221.210 at 2013-07-14 23:53:09 +0000
2013-07-14T23:53:09.514335+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2013-07-14T23:53:09.622655+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 108ms
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:6:in `index'
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in `current_cart'
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-14T23:53:09.624409+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Cart with id=1):
2013-07-14T23:53:09.627892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=pxdirect.herokuapp.com fwd="108.2.221.210" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=149ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-07-14T23:53:09.777019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pxdirect.herokuapp.com fwd="108.2.221.210" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=0
```

### Products controller

```
  def index
          @products = Product.search(params)
      unless current_cart.nil?
          @cart = current_cart
      else
          @cart = nil
      end
  end
```

### index view

```
 <% unless @cart.nil? %>
      <% if @cart.total_quantity > 0 %>
          <b>Cart&nbsp;(<%=@cart.total_quantity%>&nbsp;items)&nbsp;</b><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
      <% else %>
          <b>Cart&nbsp;</b><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
      <% end %>
 <% else %>
      <b>Cart&nbsp;</b><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
 <% end %>
```

### applicationcontroller

```
def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
          @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
          session[:cart_id] = nil if @current_cart.purchased_at
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end
```

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: May be you just don't have cart with id 1 in heroku database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to handle `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error:

```
def current_cart

  if session[:cart_id]
    begin
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil if @current_cart.purchased_at
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      create_cart
    end
  else
    create_cart
  end

  @current_cart
end

def create_cart
  @current_cart = Cart.create!
  session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
end
```

This could be caused by invalid session data.